# Ubuntu VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, ubuntu-14.04, wireless-bridge

I've been having a hard time connecting my Ubuntu server to the WiFi. Here's the situation. I have a windows 10 as host and the Ubuntu as guest in virtaualbox and I istablished a connection between the two via bridged network. The ping goes both ways The problem is when the host is connected via WiFi the guest is not. But when I use Ethernet cable the guest connect to the internet as well.

Comment: Bridging and WiFi don’t really play together. Unless VirtualBox does “MAC NAT” it just won’t work. However, it appears you’re just bridged to the wrong adapter. Did you try explicitly setting it to WiFi yet?

Comment: As @DanielB says, you have selected the wrong network adapter to bridge. You can in fact bridge both the LAN port and WIFI port at the same time if you want.

Comment: Yeah I tried bridging the LAN adapter and Host-Only and WiFi all the same time, without plugin the LAN cable without success. Even tried bridging lan adapter with host only without WiFi adapter, the host connected to WiFi and can ping the bridged network which I assigned with static IP but the guest not connected to internet

Comment: I’m not sure what you did, but it doesn’t sound correct. VirtualBox does not automatically select the adapter to bridge to. Go to your VM’s network settings and check it’s set to bridge to the correct network adapter (WiFi).

Comment: No I didn't say it got selected automatically, I did it by going to the bridge adapter properties I checked LAN adapter and unchecked wifi adapter